# How we use SASS-Compass to design our VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce

How we use SASS-Compass to design our VisualForce page?  Where we place .scss files? And how to compile .scss files?

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Anuray! Please understand that providing more info on a question will help others answering you. Could you explain SASS, what you're trying to do and what you've already tried ?

Comment: Sass is an extension of CSS3, adding nested rules, variables, mixins, selector inheritance, and more. It’s translated to well-formatted, standard CSS using the command line tool or a web-framework plugin.   There are  number of frameworks built with Sass. Compass is one of that. I am trying to style my page using SASS-Compass. I already did Sass-Compass on normal HTML page. Here I use Commands for compiling .scss files.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce cannot compile SASS, LESS, or any other web pre-compiled languages. Any code you add to salesforce must be in a CSS format to use in Visualforce. If you use Grunt to manage your compile task for SASS, I know there is a grunt plugin that allows a deployment to Salesforce as a static resource. I've automated a deployment process that automatically deployed my compiled LESS and JavaScript to Salesforce whenever I ran the compile task.

Comment: Can we have more information about this automated deployment process?

Comment: @mcmc I used this grunt task (https://github.com/kevinohara80/grunt-ant-sfdc) to run an ant deploy to my sandbox after creating the static resource metadata file and compressing all the necessary files into a zip.