# Using SASS/SCSS with Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, stylesheets, css3

We are building Lightning Web Components and styling each one using the CSS file within each component folder. This is starting to become long and out of control.

I understand that one could upload a CSS file as a static resource and import it with `loadStyle` into the relevant components, but my experience has been that this does not allow you to edit the CSS file on the fly.

**What is the best way of using SASS/SCSS with Lightning Web Components, assuming this is possible?**

My background has mostly been in React, where this is easy and well-documented, though I understand that Lightning Web Components are very new!

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/63299/60368

Comment: @OlehBerehovskyi you may want to add it as answer with the note that the statement is also true for aura / lightning components and require a custom build step if desired.. don`t think anything else can / needs to be said for now :) (and if somebody has a ready to use solution he just can add it )

Comment: Thanks for your responses - glad to know I'm not the first ever to have this problem but it's a pity there's no readymade solution!

Answer (score 7):

Answering my own question with the hacky workaround I've settled with for now.

Basically making a folder of the SCSS files outside of the codebase, then running a `sass` command where the output is the CSS file that is in the folder of the LWC itself, ie.:

```
sass --no-source-map --watch \
some/path/to/component1.scss:different/path/to/lwc/component1/component1.css \
some/path/to/component2.scss:different/path/to/lwc/component2/component2.css
```

`--no-source-map` is necessary since you won't be able to deploy your LWCs if they have an unexpected `.css.map` file in them.

Obviously far from "the best" but adequate for now.

Comment: I also needed this. I saw that if I create a subfolder, lets say scss under root, and then if I create the same tree structure as in lwc folder then with sass --no-source-map --watch scss:force-app/main/default/lwc I do not have to specify anymore each file. So I will have root/scss/lwc1/lwc1.scss and I will get root/force-app/main/default/lwc/lwc1/lwc1.css Hth